# XCode app store build - new target or configuration?

Tags: iphone, xcode, build-script, buildconfiguration

I have an app with 3 targets. Or schemes. Each target have two configs, dubug and release. I am building it in command line using build script.

For ad hoc release I use the configuration 'release'. But what about when make an appstore build. Whats the best way? To make a new target or a new configuration for app store?

Is it possible to make a new configuration for app store build, copying the values from the release. I cant find that option in my XCode 4.6 build settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select your project file under the Project Navigator
2. Select the project under 'PROJECT'
3. Click on the plus sign '+' under configurations to create a new configuration
4. Select the configuration that you want to copy the settings from

[image: Project configuration]

In our case, we use both different targets and configurations. We usually have a 'Beta' configuration for enabling traces, crash reports and shortcuts inside the Application and also have a different target to allow us having AppStore and Development versions installed in the same device without conflicts.

Cheers!

Comment: I am using xcode 4.6 and I found not section with Configuration.

Comment: Thanks I got it now. I have to select the project and then in the info tab i'll get it.

Comment: I use same app store and ad hoc to make it easy for testers and server env to test the push notification. How do you manage that?

Comment: Our push server handles development and distribution environments separately. Take into account that signing certificate is different for AppStore and development environment. For what is worth, distribution and development targets are completely different applications. This has revealed to be less error-prone that changing the signing identity by hand depending on the desired environment.